# Get String values from XML Resource file in global scope

Tags: java, android, saripaar

I am using Android Validation [Saripaar](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar) Library for validation, I need to assign my XML Resource strings to message attribute,
I'm unable to get System Resources by getResources.getStrings(R.strings.myString) at this scope because "this" is not accessible outside local scope.

```
    public class signup extends Activity 
    {
        @Order(1)
        @Email(message =  "Please Type Correct Email!")
        private EditText email;
        //onCreate()....
    }
```

Comment: this issue is somehow resolved by defining constant string. 
here is the solution

Comment: ' public final String str = R.string.error_field_required '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as follows

```
@Email(messageResId = R.string.invalid_email)
@BindView(R.id.et_mail)
EditText etMail;


From source code of saripar

@ValidateUsing(EmailRule.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Email {
    boolean allowLocal()    
default false;

    int sequence()          default -1;
    int messageResId()      default -1;
    String message()        default "Invalid email";
}
```

Comment: @Email required string in constant, we have to define it 'final' before use

Comment: which version of Saripaar are u using? bcoz i am able to do like this with com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0.3

Comment: android-saripaar:2.0.3

Comment: Sorry, I was making some mistake.
Thanks it works now

Comment: if answer helped u,mark as right answer so that user with similar situation can use this solution.

Comment: again show me an error on this statement
**@Email(messageResId = R.string.error_invalid_email)**

Comment: incompatible types. java.lang.string required int